# How to clamp Camera in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've tried this, but everytime when I pressed the display, camera start from this point.
So I don't know what to do now

I've tried to do some with clamp, but it goes wrong

```
if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began ) 
{
    firstpoint = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
    ???xAngTemp = Mathf.Clamp(xAngle, 10, 10);
    ???yAngTemp = Mathf.Clamp (yAngle, 10, 10);
    xAngTemp = xAngle;
    yAngTemp = yAngle;
}

if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase==TouchPhase.Moved) 
{
    secondpoint = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
    ???xAngTemp = Mathf.Clamp(xAngle, 10, 10);
    ???yAngTemp = Mathf.Clamp (yAngle, 10, 10);

    //Mainly, about rotate camera. For example, for Screen.width rotate on 180 degree
    xAngle = xAngTemp + (secondpoint.x - firstpoint.x) * 30 * XSensitivity / Screen.width;
    yAngle = yAngTemp - (secondpoint.y - firstpoint.y) * 15 * YSensitivity / Screen.height;

    //Rotate camera
    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0.0f);
}
```

Comment: can u explain what do you want ?! what do you mean by Clamp Camera?

Comment: I mean to make camera rotate only by 90 degreese

Answer (score 0):

first a speed Variable called RotSpeed :

```
float RotSpeed = 1;
```

then modify your update function like this:

```
rotX += Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x * RotSpeed;
rotY += Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y * RotSpeed;
rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, -90f, 90f);
rotY = Mathf.Clamp(rotY, -90f, 90f);
Camera.main.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotX * 5, Space.Self);
Camera.main.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, rotY * 5, Space.Self);
```

Comment: NoI know how to do it for PC
I dont know how to do it in my code for Android

Comment: then replace Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") with Input.GetTouch(0).position.x
and Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") with Input.GetTouch(0).position.y

Comment: No it doesnt works for phone
I gave you my code, just look in it
It didnt work((

Comment: I ve done , thanks
I made 
xAngle = Mathf.Clamp(xAngle, -70f, 70f);
yAngle = Mathf.Clamp(yAngle, -70f, 70f);
Without "-" operator

Comment: try this : replace Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") with  Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x;

and  Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") with Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y;

Comment: I said it doesnt work
But thanks for first piece
I forget to change from 70 to -70

Comment: can you replace  this Camera.main.transform.rotation  = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, 0f);
 with Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (rotX, rotY, 0.0f);

Comment: Thats cool but now it didnt rotate for horizontal(((((((((((((
xAngle = Mathf.Clamp(xAngle, -70f, 70f);
yAngle = Mathf.Clamp(yAngle, -70f, 70f);

Comment: mmm, try replacing Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, 0f); with this : 
Camera.main.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, rotX * 5, Space.Self);
Camera.main.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left, rotY * 5, Space.Self);

Answer (score 0):

Im stupid
To fix horizontal rotation just should remove yClamp)))
Thanks a lot
So rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, -90f, 90f); actually works
Im just stupid, ive made it without - operator first)